# not able to change style attribute using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: First situation]

I want a small change in all `style` attribute of 'image' class in a HTML document.

So i do this-

[image: Second Situation]

In console window, the change is done and it returns new changed `style` attribute.

But It remains unchanged in Element windows of chrome and show no effect of change.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP doesn't understand that the code serving the markup needs to change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you are just replacing the value but not implementing it to element.

Assign the value to new var and then apply it on the element like this

```
var carGgrDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
var newStyle = carGgrDivs[56].getAttribute('style').replace(/(_)(\d)/, "$12");
carGgrDivs.setAttribute('style',newStyle);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since getAttribute returns a value, you are calling replace on that value, so the element never gets it's attribute updated.

try this:

```
var updatedStyle = el.getAttribute('style').replace(/(_)(\d)/, "$12");
el.setAttribute('style', updatedStyle);
```

where el is the element you're trying to update.

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the value, so you get the result in the console, but you do not store it anywhere, so DOM does not change. You need to use setAttribute() method in this case: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

It would go something like this:

```
var updatedAttr = carGgrDivs[56].getAttribute('style').replace(...);
carGgrDivs[56].setAttribute('style', updatedAttr);
```